# What should be the languages to develop applications for a Nokia 5130?

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia

I want to develop an application for [Nokia 5130 XpressMusic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_5130), so I need to know, which language should I use to develop this application?

1. QT
2. Java-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use Qt to develop for Nokia 5130 because this mobile is based on Symbian series 40.

Qt is [supported on the Series 60 of Symbian](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Support_for_Symbian).

Comment: You are completely wrong, though NOKIA 5130 runs on Nokia OS. Platform, Series 40 5th Edition, it's based on J2ME, and i've developed and run successfully my application on NOKIA 5200, AND 5130

Comment: please read my answer again. I told it is not possible to use Qt for Nokia 5130 (Read his question title again)

Comment: yeah they got expired just 1 week ago, will renew soon :)

Comment: @emaillenin but he did not asked about QT :|

Comment: @Sourav laalto edited the question title after I answered. The question started with Qt earlier..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  You need to know Java ME [Java 2 mobile edition, CLDC/MIDP], try it with the NetBeans.

Comment: my question is... is it possible or not?

Comment: I meant to ask... is that mobile can support to install the application.

Comment: is there any api for j2me. i want to download that api.